# Force WCF to accept only TLS12 protocol

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5, tls1.2

I have a WCF target on framework 4.5 and  hosted on IIS (windows server 2012), calling the service from c# client with all the security protocols (SSL, TLS, TLS12) is working properly, is it possible to set the WCF service to accept only the TLS12 security protocol?

Comment: If you are talking about restricting what protocols are accepted at the host's end then this is not a programming task. See this question on serverfault... https://serverfault.com/questions/733994/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-in-windows-2012-rdp

Comment: This is valid only to force client to communicate with TLS12.
Server side is not possible to set this code.

Comment: @quaabaam I Think this is right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official document guidance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
We had better not specify the TLS version, it is advisable to let the OS decide on the TLS version.
We could specify the TLS version by the below code on the client-side, provided that the `operation system` and project’s runtime environment meet the requirement. For more details, please refer to the above link.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thx for the replay, great article, but modify registry (Configuring Schannel protocols in the Windows Registry) not force the WCF service hosted by IIS to use only TLS1.2 it work with all others protocol

Comment: this might not an advisable way to configure it on the server-side.

Comment: Now work, I need only to restart Server after Registry change. thx.